# How did they assemble the head collection at New New Yorks Head Museum?

Tags: futurama

I love the Head Museum! How did they manage to get their lively pre 30th century exibits?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [The Infosphere](http://theinfosphere.org/Head_jars) states:

> The fluid that preserves the heads contains a very very small amount of powder made from opals. Such powder is capable of maintaining the heads by creating a temporal stasis, where they are kept with the same youth as they had in their respective eras.

The explanation of this powder ([Crystalline Opal](http://theinfosphere.org/Crystalline_Opal)) and its properties appears in the episode ["All the Presidents' Heads"](http://theinfosphere.org/All_the_Presidents%27_Heads).

The manner in which all the heads at the museum were collected is never explained, but due to the temporal effects of the opal powder it is quite likely that a skull could simply be dug up from a grave and then placed in a jar containing the powder, thus returning the head to the state it was in when still alive.

Comment: +1 for the very reasonable explanation of where the heads may have come from.

Comment: I thought the youthful vigor came from a healthy diet of Torgo's Executive Powder. It has a million and one uses!

Comment: @ErikNoren: The temporal effects of the opal powder are short-lasting on those who *drink it*, so perhaps a diet of Torgo's Executive Powder extends these temporal effects for the heads?