# How were the heads reanimated in the future?

Tags: futurama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did they assemble the head collection at New New Yorks Head Museum?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18201/how-did-they-assemble-the-head-collection-at-new-new-yorks-head-museum)

How were all of the heads reanimated to be talking in the future?

It is possible (in Futurama-Lore) to put someone's head in a jar and have them live like a fish in water.

But how did they make all of the people come back to life and put them into jars?

Is there any in-universe explanation for it?

Comment: @gnovice RATS! I searched and I could not find it.... :-(