# What is the lifespan of Humans in Futurama?

Tags: futurama

As you see in Futurama, people can be very old and still function.  The Professor is over 150 and you even see Werstrom passing 120(?).  Mom, from Mom's Friendly Robot Company is even older.

When do people start to die from old age in Futurama?

Comment: Do you have a source for Mom being older?  The Professor is a bit over 160 at this point, not 150. ([source episode](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Clone_of_My_Own))

Comment: @Keen, I said *over* 150.  And Mom established MomCorp when 2881, In Nibblers dialogue(Bender's Big Game), it flash-backed, showing that her appearance hasn't changed, while Farnsworth has been shown over the years as balding.

Comment: @Keen Presumably Mom wouldn't get carted off by the Sunset Squad Robots right?

Comment: @NominSim The comment over on the Sunset Squad question raises the valid point that if they're Mom robots, she has control of them.

Answer (score 11):

It's not really known, since most people (with the exception of the [Professor](http://theinfosphere.org/Professor_Hubert_J._Farnsworth)) aren't allowed to age naturally past 160 years old. At that point, the [Sunset Squad](http://theinfosphere.org/Sunset_Squad_Robot) collects them and brings them to the [Near Death Star](http://theinfosphere.org/Near_Death_Star) where they are placed in a Matrix-like virtually reality retirement home. How long they last there has never been mentioned.

The Professor escaped the Near Death Star in the episode ["A Clone of My Own"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Clone_of_My_Own), which would make him one of the oldest naturally-living humans at 171 years old (currently).

**NOTE:** I assume you a referring to the lifespan of an *entire* human, because *human heads* can clearly live in jars for what would appear to be an indefinite amount of time (well over one thousand years) without further aging. This is the result of temporal stasis, as explained in [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18201/2287).

Comment: -1 Beat me to it! :(

Answer (score 3):

As the episode [Near-Death Wish](http://theinfosphere.org/Near-Death_Wish) shows, the Professor's parents are still alive, which means people can live at least 190 years in the future.

Math: The Professor was 160 in <strike>2000</strike> [3000](http://theinfosphere.org/A_clone_of_my_own), so he's now 172 in <strike>2012</strike> 3012.  Add ~20 years to get a rough minimum of his parent's age.

Answer (score -1):

His parents seem to have been more in there late 20s I'd say when you see them young in the episode where they rescue the professors parents from the near death Star so roughly I think it could be about 10 years more so I'd say around 200 to 203

Comment: You appear to be responding to another user's answer here, in a way that makes your answer incomplete when taken on its own. You could fix this by editing your answer to include the relevant information from the other answer, to fully show how you worked out the final age range of 200-203.